# How to add field value on RulesChecker message

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to add entity value "$entity->from_date" to rule message.

```
public function buildRules(\Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules)
{
   $rules->addCreate(function ($entity, $options) {    
      ....
      return true;    
   }, 'customRules', [
      'errorField' => 'error',
      'message' => 'This date = '.$date.' is exist.'
   ]);
}
```

$date value is $entity->from_date->i18nFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to validation rules, application rules can return a string instead of boolean `false`, it indicates a failure too, and the string will be used as the error message.

It is however required that the `errorField` option is present, otherwise the rule will fail silently, without setting an error on the entity!

```
$rules->addCreate(
    function ($entity, $options) {    
        // ...

        return 'Custom error message that can include values from $entity.';    
    },
    'ruleName',
    [
        'errorField' => 'field_name'
    ]
);
```

<strike>It probably wouldn't hurt if this were documented in the Cookbook...</strike> Now it is.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Validating Data > Applying Application Rules > Conditional/Dynamic Error Messages](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#conditional-dynamic-error-messages)**